# First principal component separate the clusters but other PCs not

Tags: clustering, pca, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I have two sets of vcf files with different samples but from the same population. I merged the two and want to compare the two sets via PCA analysis.

Since the two set is from the same population I expect an overlap on the PCA. But when I plot the pca results, (PC1 vs PC2), there is a shift in the first PC but not on the second. When I plot PC2 vs PC3, PC3 vs PC4 etc. there is a nice overlap.

Do you know why there is a shift in PC1 only? one set clusters around zero and the other not. The direction is exactly the same.

Comment: PCA doesn't try to separate clusters *per se*. Discriminant function analysis or support vector machines might be a better bet depending on in what sense you want to separate the clusters.

Comment: Any random difference *ought* to be most pronounced in the first principal component.  This makes it difficult to see what the problem is with your result.

Comment: I am not trying to separate clusters. I am trying to show that the two sets of samples are coming from the same population. After PCA, if there is an overlap i could say that the two sets are the same. But in my case, there is a shift in the first PC only while there is a nice overlap with the other PCs.

Comment: Are these the VCF files used for [genome sequence variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format#The_VCF_header)? If so, which columns are you doing PCA on and how are you doing that? The 8 mandatory columns aren't readily amenable to PCA. If you are evaluating things like variants-allele fractions on multiple genes from multiple individuals, how are you combining the within-individual and across-individual values? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.